# Asteroid Impact Sites Topographic Data

Tags: data-request

I am trying to find a source for various topographic maps and aerial/drone imagery of asteroid impact sites for a project I have coming up.

Are there any specific sources that focus on this topic, or LIDAR and multispectral data that can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I typed into google "meteor impact locations" and got this -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Impact_Database